# Static API: Как конкретно коэффициент масштабирования масштабирует карту? Есть ли опция добавить пометку с масштабом?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

Почитал документацию по поводу параметра `z` в Static API - коэффициент масштабирования. Но, что именно на него умножается или делится? Есть ли вариант прикрепить поверх обозначение масштаба?

Такого вида:

[image: Пример]

Comment: Возможно, это будет полезно (это для API 2.0, в 2.1 тоже должно быть подобное): https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/control.ScaleLine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Масштаб в **Яндекс Картах** не значит ничего, кроме порядкового номера набора тайлов подложки, начиная с нулевого, когда вся карта отображена одним тайлом. При увеличении масштаба на единицу каждый тайл предыдущего зума делится на 4 более подробных тайла.

При этом на разных широтах тайлы одного масштаба будут представлять разную реальную длину, поскольку используется [проекция Меркатора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0).

Если вы сможете на своей стороне вычислять реальные размеры по широте получаемого изображения, можете попробовать и линейку нарисовать для примерной оценки размеров сторонними средствами.